# Disable HTML cache on Cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare

I want to add a website to Cloudflare, but we implemented some personalization functionalities, as i know by default Cloudflare will cache  the whole HTML page, and this will impact our  personalization functionality, is here any way to disable this option i just want to use it to cache assets like: css, js and images, No need for HTML cache.

Answer (score 1):

> By default, Cloudflare's CDN  does not cache HTML content. HTML
>   updates will show immediately. Only static content like Javascript,
>   images and CSS would be cached by default. You can, however, create
>   PageRules to cache things like static HTML.

Source: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168216--Does-Cloudflare-cache-HTML-content-